# How to list all members from Azure AD group with their extensionattributes?

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

How would I list all members from Azure AD group with their extensionattributes?

e.g.

```
Name UPN extensionAttribute1 extensionAttribute2 ...
```

I assume that PowerShell can be used to do this.

Comment: Have you tried researching this? Found any possible commands you _might_ use? Any code you've tried that doesn't work yet? You need to show you've tried finding a solution yourself, as at the moment it looks like you're expecting us to do all the work for you...

Comment: @JamesC. I am only asking, because I haven't found anything. I do not think that listing references to regular AD cmdlets (e.g. Get-ADUser) is going to make the question better or prove that I have tried to find solution.